# Copy image or video to gallery - Android studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I copy photos or videos to another folder using the following codes:

```
override fun onButtonClick(position: Int) {
    val origin = File(statuses[position]) // Addresses of photos or videos are stored in the mutable list of statuses
    val destination = if (statuses[position].endsWith(".jpg"))
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + '/' + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + FilePath.PICTURES_DIRECTORY + '/' + Random.nextInt() + ".jpg")
    else File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + '/' + Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + FilePath.VIDEO_DIRECTORY + '/' + Random.nextInt() + ".mp4")
    origin.copyTo(destination)
}
```

The file is copied and shown in the file manager.
But I can't find that copied file in gallery.
How can I show it in the gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use the MediaScannerConnection class to notify the media scanner about the new file?

```
override fun onButtonClick(position: Int) {
val origin = File(statuses[position])
val destination = if (statuses[position].endsWith(".jpg"))
    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + '/' + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + FilePath.PICTURES_DIRECTORY + '/' + Random.nextInt() + ".jpg")
else File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + '/' + Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + FilePath.VIDEO_DIRECTORY + '/' + Random.nextInt() + ".mp4")
origin.copyTo(destination)

// Notify the media scanner about the new file
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
    applicationContext,
    arrayOf(destination.absolutePath),
    null,
    null
)
}
```

and don't forget to add the necessary permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way:

```
       val appDirectoryName = "XYZ"
            val imageRoot = File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                ), appDirectoryName
            )
```

This creates a new file in the gallery and give you the root for the location

AKA: destination